# How to test addEventListener and removeEventListener in vue mounted/Unmounted

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, vuejs3

I have a problem with addEventListener and removeEventListener. It shows that removeEventListener is uncovered, sadly i have no idea how i should test it.

Code:

```
const isMobile = ref(false);

onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => (isMobile.value = setIsMobile()));
});

onUnmounted(() => {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", () => (isMobile.value = setIsMobile())); //<--- This line is uncovered 
});

isMobile.value = setIsMobile();
```

Answer (score 0):

element.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown, true);

Define an seperate handler instead of directly the handler within the listener itself

```
const isMobile = ref(false);
const resizeHandler = () => {
 isMobile.value = setIsMobile()
}
onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler, true); // Call the handler within
});

onUnmounted(() => {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeHandler, true); // Call the handler within
});

isMobile.value = setIsMobile();
```